# How to set color of flycheck-posframe

Tags: colors, emacs

I am new come to emacs, but now got some problems, i cant set color of flycheck-posframe , what is correct way to set it.i had try write this but it cant work. thanks

```lisp
    (setq  flycheck-posframe-warning-prefix ""
           flycheck-posframe-error-prefix ""
           flycheck-posframe-border-width 5
           flycheck-posframe-error-face '((t :inherit nil :foreground "red"))
           flycheck-posframe-warning-face `(:foreground-color ."orange")
           flycheck-posframe-info-face '((t (:foreground "blue")))
           flycheck-posframe-border-face  '(:foreground "#dc752f")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faces in Emacs are actually stored differently than normal variables are, which means that you can't set their values using `setq`.

The easiest way to modify face attributes is through the [Emacs Customization interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html). You can do so by running the command `M-x customize-face` and then entering in the name of the face you want to change. You can easily edit attributes of the face in this customization buffer. Once you finish making changes, you must either select `Apply` (if you want the changes to apply for the current Emacs session) or `Apply and Save` (if you want the changes to persist to future Emacs sessions as well) to have the changes occur.

Here's an example of using the customization buffer to modify `flycheck-posframe-error-face`:
[image: emacs customization screencast example]

If for some reason you need to modify the face attributes using Emacs Lisp, however, you can do so using the `set-face-attribute` function. This function takes the name of the face (as a symbol), a frame (the value of `nil` means the change affects all frames), and alternating attribute names and values. Note that these attribute changes will only affect the current Emacs session. You would need to execute these functions each time you start an Emacs session for these changes to apply to that session (e.g. by adding the following commands to your init file).

The following should make the modifications you were attempting to make:

```
(set-face-attribute 'flycheck-posframe-error-face
                    nil
                    :inherit nil
                    :foreground "red")

(set-face-attribute 'flycheck-posframe-warning-face
                    nil
                    :foreground "orange")

(set-face-attribute 'flycheck-posframe-info-face
                    nil
                    :foreground "blue")

(set-face-attribute 'flycheck-posframe-border-face
                    nil
                    :foreground "#dc752f")
```